# EXCEL 2010 recalculating open file. How to disable it?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a problem with Excel and one program. When I open a 7Mb Excel file it takes 500MB of RAM and opening time of 15 seconds. But if this file is open and I want to open in my program OLE EXCEL with another program I am stuck and waiting for recalculation of the opened file... a partial solution is to disable recalculation formulas in big file...but I do not want to do this...

The big file and OLE do not have any common formulas or data.

Why Excel opening OLE in this process? How to separate them?

Answer (score 1):

**I would like to suggest two different methods to Stop RECALCULATION while open the File or better say STOP AUTO RECALCULATION.**

**Method 1:** Switch the Automatic (Default) Calculation option to Manual.

**Method 2:**

```
Private Sub App_WorkbookOpen(ByVal Wb As Workbook)

    With Application
        .Calculation = xlManual
        .MaxChange = 0.001
        .CalculateBeforeSave = False

    End With

End Sub
```

*Hope this help you.*